# Simple answer for multiple choice question

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I am writing a question, and I have something like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Choice 1
      \item Choice 2
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

and now I want to show the solution to this question. Is there a simple way of doing this? I just want a simple thing; using a package will be an overhead.

I tried adding `\label{answer:q}` after `Choice 2`, but when I use `\ref{answer:q}` it gives me `1b` for the second choice, the `1` here is referring to the the parent `\item`, can I restrict this to the child `\item` to get only `b`?

Comment: Well that is exactly what it is supposed to be doing, right? Labels reference the number and pages etc. In this case you would have to create a command for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\p@enumii` (the prefix used):

```
\documentclass{article}          

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Ans[1]{\par The answer is~\ref{#1}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1 
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Choice 1
      \item Choice 2\label{test}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\Ans{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Wuth the help of the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you can define a dedicated list for the choices, and you can easily customize the label and string used for cross-references:

```
\documentclass{article}          
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[choices]{label=(\alph*),ref=(\alph*)}

\newcommand\Ans[1]{\par The answer is~\ref{#1}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question 1 
    \begin{choices}
      \item Choice 1
      \item Choice 2\label{test}
    \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}
\Ans{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]